# How to remove the value 0 from the input

Tags: angular, typescript

Do you know how I can make the value 0 disappear in the input? I find it very annoying...

[image]

I'm looking to do this using a best practice.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

  nb: number = 0; 
  resultElement: string = "";

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  checkNumber(): void {
    if(this.nb > 0){
      this.resultElement = "The number is positive";
    } else if (this.nb < 0){
      this.resultElement = "The number is negative";
    } else {
      this.resultElement = "The number is zero";
    }
  }

}
```

If I replace it

```
nb: number = 0;
```

With that

```
nb: any;
```

Or

```
nb: number | null = null;
```

The problem is solved, but is it the best practice?

Comment: You have to set the value to an empty string, instead of a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `!` postfix expression with the property declaration. It tells TypeScript that the property will definitely be assigned. For example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  nb!: number;
}
```